# Static if expression in D?

Tags: d

How can I simulate a static if expression (not statement) in D?

```
auto foo = (({ static if (cond) { return altA; } else { return altB; })());
```

This works, but creates a delegate and ldc errors out if you nest delegates. I'm sure it can be done as an expr with some template magic, I'm just not good enough at it yet.

Comment: Can you give a complete sample usage code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `static if` doesn't create a new scope, you can just do this:

```
static if (cond)
    auto foo = altA;
else
    auto foo = altB;

// Use foo here as normal
foo.fun();
```

If you really want it to be an expression, you can do this:

```
template ifThen(bool b, alias a, alias b) {
    static if (b)
        alias ifThen = a;
    else
        alias ifThen = b;
}

auto foo = ifThen!(cond, altA, altB);
```

There are some limitations of `alias` parameters that may make this solution suboptimal, so it may or may not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I coded in D, but did you try this as a workaround?

```
static if (cond)
  auto foo = altA(); 
else 
  auto foo = altB();
```

Contrary to C++, this is legal in D

Comment: Or rather you can't use `foo` after the static-if-else statement, Because C++'s `if constexpr` introduces a scope. A huuuuge mistake: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcyb1lpEHm0&feature=youtu.be&t=2715

Comment: @Nordlöw I 100% do agree